# Which are 3d convex object slicing algorithms (which is there complexity)?

Tags: algorithm

I wonder what are most fast (in terms of `O(N)`) algorithms that having a convex three dimentional object and its left top bounding box corner positioned in some XYZ can prvide its cross section with some plane defined by 3 points of 3d space?

Comment: Is the object a polygon? If not, how is it specified?

Comment: Object is convex hull, which we slice via plane

Comment: Yes, in that case my answer will work for you. (You'll have to implement it, but it really isn't that hard.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible algorithm (assuming the object is a convex polygonal solid):

1. Compute the intersection between the plane and each edge of the object. If the edge is coplanar with the plane, then just assume it intersects at each endpoint of the edge.
2. Sort the intersection points in clockwise order.

That's it. The intersection between a plane and a convex polygonal solid must be itself a convex polygon, and this simple algorithm gives you exactly the points of the polygon.

Since calculating the intersection of a plane and an edge takes constant time, the time is `O(E + K log K)`, where `E` is the number of edges in the solid and `K` is the number of intersection points (points in the final polygon). `K` might on the order of `E` in the worst case, so the total running time is `O(E log E)` in the worst case.

Comment: I had another idea - project all object points on plane (but do not know complexity metrics for point to plane projection) and getting hull on resulting 2d plane points.

Comment: I don't think that works, actually. Projection might result in points that lie outside the actual cross section. Just consider the example of a triangle (-1,1), (0,0), (1,0). If you project that triangle down to the x-axis, the result is the interval [-1,1], but the actual intersection is [0,1]. The triangle is surely convex.

Comment: Point to plane projection, though, is very cheap (constant time), and convex hull is also very cheap (O(V log V)). So it would be a fast but wrong algorithm :)